# Find $AD\cdot AF$ when point $C$ is reflected across $AD$

Tags: geometry, reflection

$ABC$ is a triangle with side lengths $AB=AC=20$ and $BC=18$. $D$ is a point on $BC$ such that $BD<CD$. $C$ is reflected across $AD$ and lands on $E$. $EB$ and $AD$ meet at $F$. Find $AD\cdot AF$. No progress at all. This is my first question where I have seen points getting reflected and I really have no idea how to approach this question. Any help would be appreciated. Also is there any sort of "name" given to these categories of problems?

Edit: The question is indeed correct and the answer is $400$. But I have no clue how to get that value.

Here is a Geogebra diagram: (not completely accurate) https://www.geogebra.org/classic/hecrtmsd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $AE=AC=AB\implies \angle ACF= \angle AEB=\angle ABE\implies F\in\odot(ABC)$. Now, note that $$\angle ABC=\angle ACB=\angle AFB\implies AB \text{ is tangent to } \odot(BDF) \text{ at $B$}$$Thus, by power of point,
$$400=AB^2=\mathcal P_{\odot(BDF)}(A)=AD\times AF$$

Comment: How did you directly get $AD \cdot AF$? I got $AD \cdot DF=BD \cdot DC$. And then using Stewart's theorem $AD^2+BD\cdot DC=AB^2$. From that, I got $AD \cdot AF= AB^2$. I think I am misunderstanding the meaning of the power of a point here. And how could you conclude that $AB$ is tangent to the circumcircle of $BDF$? I am sorry I am na idiot. (Did you use alternate segments theorem?)

Comment: @PopularPower I'm taking power of point $A$ wrt $\odot(BDF)$ as reference (instead of $D$ wrt $\odot(ABC)$ which you did). As $AB$ is tangent to $\odot(BDF)$, power of $A$ will be $AB^2$. Further, $AF$ intersects $\odot(BDF)$ at $D$ and $F$, so power of $A$ is also $AD\times AF$. Thus, $AB^2=AD\times AF$.

Comment: Could you just elaborate the part why $AB$ is tangent to circumcircle of $BDF$? Like which theorem did you use?

Comment: I really want to cry now with embarrassment but in order to apply the tangent-chord theorem don't we have to prove that $\angle ABD= \angle BFD$? I am really sorry for bothering you so much. I know it can be proved since ABFC is cyclic. But how did you do it?

Comment: @PopularPower My previous comment had a typo:
As ∠ABD=∠BFD, by tangent-chord theorem (or alternate segment theorem) we get the tangency. If you wanna ask why $\angle ABD=\angle BFD$, then I have already written the reason in the answer.

Comment: Did you use the fact that $ABFC$ is cyclic?

Comment: @PopularPower Yes I did! That's how you get $\angle ACB=\angle AFB$.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! You are a lifesaver. Thanks for giving up so much of your time explaining me. I am really grateful.

Comment: @PopularPower You're welcome! :)